# Get up-arrow command history in Konsole on Ubuntu

Tags: konsole

The up-arrow doesn't seem to work for command history in Konsole which I have installed in Ubuntu 19.04. Is this a KDE thing or should I change a setting somewhere?

Here are the general settings of my profile:

[image]

Comment: Which shell is your Konsole configured to use as the "Command" (in Settings > Manage Profiles > Edit profile > General iirc)?

Comment: @steeldriver looks like plain old /bin/bash

Comment: Does your `~/.bash_history` file exist and if yes is it empty?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $HISTSIZE`?

Comment: $HISTSIZE is 1000 and my ~/.bash_history is populated with the correct history , even in Konsole.

Comment: Actually just installed Konsole on a virgin Ubuntu 19.04 virtual machine and up arrow works fine. I'm assuming my current system, which has tons of stuff installed with gpu drivers etc and various kernel patches, is a bit "out". I'll be deleting question tomorrow but just wanted to say thank you for attempts at help, and I did learn something with ~/.bash_history which is very useful actually!